# How can I get the value of pole capacitor and zero resistor in LT1575's open_loop ac analyze

Tags: ltspice

I want to ask the LT1575. Is this my circle connection problem? Why the C4, C3,and Rz can not affect the phase margin in open-loop analyze.

[image]

Improved image: -

[image]